# Is it possible to check the python source code of a node?

Tags: node-editor

I remember seeing somewhere that it was possible to view the python source code of a menu button and other things.

Is it possible to see the implementation of the NodeSocketInterfaceFloat?

Comment: I think for the sake of speed, nodes are not written in Python but in C/C++. You might have some luck asking that question over there https://blender.chat/channel/blender-coders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes are implemented in C/C++, not in Python. Yes, they can be added to a menu with Python, but the node system itself would become way too slow when it would be implemented in that language.

Comment: Yeah, after searching a bit more, i managed to find the C++ implementation.
I thought that they were using just a base and then implementing other dependencies with python, but anyway, thank you!