# Adding a custom Python function as a node

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, color

I've just started learning Blender a day ago so excuse me if this is a basic question! Let's say I want to specify a position-dependent color on Blender's default cube. One way to do it is to do the following:

[image]

Now I was wondering if instead of Blender's math node, I could write a custom Python function that takes the input number (the z coordinate), manipulates it in the way I want and outputs the number that is given to the color ramp. E.g. say I define this simple Python function:

[image]

Is there a way to replace the math node in the example with this function? I noticed that there's a script node but it doesn't seem to have any input/outputs to use for this.

[image]

This is of course just an example. In reality I want to have a much more complicated Python function. Something that's hard to do with Blender's own nodes.

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/228182/42221) by a Blender developer points out that nodes are written in C++ not Python, for performance reasons.  I think that implies that there's no way to do what you want.  (There's also no bpy interface that would support it, another clue.)

Comment: @MartyFouts I see. That's very helpful, thank you.